# Possibly a bufferbloat?

Tags: latency

not very long ago ive noticed high latency and slowdown in responsiveness in my network. what is weird is it seems to only occur from 10 am to 10 pm (been this way for a week now). 10 pm onwards it goes back to how normally it was. i checked my router's log and it was filled with PING FLOODING attacks both from WAN and LAN.

As a way to troubleshoot this, i tried running anti-malware programs, restarted both my modem and router a couple of times, plugged in and out cables, phoned my ISP but none of those seemed to mitigate the issue. After reading through forums, i tried running wireshark, and my captured network activity file shows a number of bad tcps and tcp rst. aditionally, i also ran winMTR but results show no packet loss. im not familiar with networking so ive been having a hard time locating the root of the traffic. Am i possibly experiencing the so called bufferbloat?